# Ionic 2, Chrome keeps loading from disk cache

Tags: google-chrome, ionic-framework, ionic2, browser-cache

I'm developing a mobile app and use the following command to build and run a version that works in a browser (pulling in all necessary hooks, which ionic serve does not)

```
ionic build browser --desktop --testing && http-server platforms/browser/www/
```

Yesterday, and for weeks, this works perfectly. I stop and start that same command, it builds/compiles everything, everything is great.

Then I updated Google Chrome. Now, no matter what I do, Chrome keeps pulling all of these resources from disk cache, even after I delete and re-create them. Any ideas how I can solve? I don't want to have to clear my cache out every time I reload, and it seems this'll cause additional issues down the road.

I don't know why or how this changed, no project or config settings are different in my Ionic2 app.

Using cmd-shift-R instead of just cmd-R to reload seems to force Chrome to not load from disk cache but I'm confused and want to understand what happened here...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chrome caches a lot but you can force it to load resources from your server instead of taking them out of cache by using cache busting:

Load templates:

```
var timestamp = (new Date()).getTime();

$ionicPopup.show({
    scope: $scope,
    title: 'Work!',
    templateUrl: '/templates/roll-timer-popup.html?update='+timestamp
});
```

Load scripts/stylesheets:

```
<script src="myscripts.js?update=123..."></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="theme.css?update=123...">
```

For script/stylesheets you might create them along with the timestamps dynamically and insert them afterwards.

Or when your scripts-files get bundelt together, you could use a script to write timestamps into your finally index.html file for deployment by using a nodejs-script, for I made this script for one of my projects:

```
const fs = require('fs');

var filename = process.argv[2];

var regExp = /[.|\w]+[.]js/;
var contentToAttach = ['<!-- CONTENT ATTACHED BY '+process.argv[1]+' -->','you can put other content in here that is put into at the end of your file'];

fs.readFile(filename, {
    flag : 'r',
    encoding: 'utf-8'
},(err, oldFileContent) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    var fileContent = oldFileContent;
    var oldScriptName;
    var now = (new Date()).getTime();
    var lastIndexPos = 0;
    while (oldScriptName = oldFileContent.match(regExp)) {
        var newScriptName = oldScriptName + '?update=' + now;
        var newIndexPos = fileContent.indexOf(oldScriptName);
        if (newIndexPos !== lastIndexPos) {
            fileContent = fileContent.replace(oldScriptName, newScriptName);
            lastIndexPos = newIndexPos;
        }
        else {
            // same filename found
            var fildContentSlice = fileContent.slice(newIndexPos+oldScriptName.length);
            fildContentSlice = fildContentSlice.replace(oldScriptName, newScriptName);
            fileContent = fileContent.slice(0,newIndexPos+oldScriptName.length)+fildContentSlice;
        }
        oldFileContent = oldFileContent.replace(oldScriptName, '');
    }
    var wholeContent = fileContent+'\n\r'+contentToAttach.join('\n\r');
    fs.writeFile(filename,wholeContent, (err) => {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log('File: '+filename+' is updated!');
    });
});
```

It inserts *?update=123...* in every script-tag it can find in a file.
To execute this script in the shell write:

```
node updateScript.js path_to_your_html_file
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks but this isn't the issue I'm facing exactly. Ionic2 bundles up everything into perdy packages that happen to have the same names and Chrome decided to helpful by caching these. So, it's literally everything. It'll be fine for deployed apps and the ctrl+shift+R reload I mentioned is working well enough... I just want to understand what's going on since nothing in my project changed, just updated Chrome to the latest version :-\ Very annoying

Comment: You are welcome. Sorry I dont know how chrome is implemented but I've updated my answer to help your handle bundled script-files. Hope it helps more.